# Airflow: Can the same operator instance be reused and executed many times maintaining state between runs?

Tags: python, airflow

Could you please explain is it possible under certain circumstances that operator instance can be reused and `execute()` method will be executed many times and the state is maintained between `execute()` runs?

In other words, **is this scenario possible in Airflow**:

1. self variable in Operator is initialised in **init**.
2. execute() method reads self variable and changes it.
3. execute() runs one more time on the same instance of operator for example because of restart or something else
   and can read self variable changed by previous execute run?

   ```
   class MyOperator(BaseOperator):

     def __init__(self,
                param_1
                ...
                param_n):

         self.var1=param_1

     def execute(self, context):
         #do some logic with self variable
         self.var1  += 1 #
   ```

Comment: You can't access previous runs like that. Can you explain about the problem itself ? You described here your approach for solution however there might be other ideas if you can share the problem itself.

Comment: I just want to know is it safe to modify self variables in execute method and have some logic based on it or the instance can be reused in airflow, then it is not safe and I should not touch them and use local variables derived from instance variables

Comment: @Elad I do not try to access prvious instance state in such way. I just want some confirmation that such scenario is not possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you have described is not possible for the following reason.

When Airflow Scheduler dispatches your task instance to the queue, the task is initialized each heartbeat in the worker.

This is because each heartbeat that the [DagBag](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.14/airflow/bin/cli.py#L614) is filled the operator instances are initialized.

Any value stored there between runs is reset when it's reinitialized.

If you need to store values between runs you can use the `Variable` model to store such values.

```py
from airflow.models import Variable

def execute(self, context):
    #do some logic with self variable 
    var1 = Variable.get(
            "count", 
            deserialize_json=True,
            default_var=0
        )
    var1 += 1    
    Variable.set("count", var1)
```